# drf serializer data not showing all fields data properly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**id** field and **name** field not showing in result.

in models.py:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='groups_user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

in serializers.py:

```
class SimpleUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','first_name', 'last_name')

class GroupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    admin = SimpleUserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id','name','admin')
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def getSomeGroup(request):
    allGroup = Group.objects.all().count()
    randomGroupId = random.sample(range(allGroup), 3)
    randomGroup = Group.objects.filter(id__in=randomGroupId)
    serializer = GroupSerializer(randomGroup, many=True)
    #print(serializer)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

the result comes like this:

[{"admin":{"id":1,"first_name":"asif","last_name":""}},{"admin":{"id":3,"first_name":"Test2","last_name":"lastname"}},{"admin":{"id":3,"first_name":"Test2","last_name":"lastname"}}]

why **id** and **name** field not showing?

Answer (score 0):

```
class SimpleUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

> First try to access all admin

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes(IsAuthenticated)
def getSomeGroup(request):
    randomGroup = Group.objects.all()
    serializer = GroupSerializer(randomGroup, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

> > If that works there may be issue in your these two line
> > The Issue may be in these two lines

```
allGroup = Group.objects.all().count()
randomGroupId = random.sample(range(allGroup), 3)
```

Comment: try to print randomGroup at terminal/cmd and if output dosen't comes there is issue in get or database.

Answer (score 0):

Modify serializers.py:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```